# How to make a table row clickable and expand the row - vue.js - element-ui

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I am using table that has expandable row feature. The row expands when the expand icon is clicked, you can check the example [HERE](http://element.eleme.io/#expandable-row). But, what I am trying to make is, the **entire row** clickable and toggle expand and collapse the row just like it works when the expand icon is clicked.

Please help.

Here is my markup:

```
<template lang="pug">
  el-table(:data="tableData")
    el-table-column(label="Employee Name", prop="userName")
    el-table-column(label="Company Name", prop="companyName")
    el-table-column(type="expand", align="right" )
      template(slot-scope="props")
        p User Name: {{ props.row.userName }}
        p Company Name: {{ props.row.companyName }}
</template>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Alright, I figured out the solution and answering my own question :)

Markup:

```
<template lang="pug">
  el-table(:data="tableData", @row-click="rowClicked", ref="tableData").clickable-rows
    el-table-column(label="Employee Name", prop="userName")
    el-table-column(label="Company Name", prop="companyName")
    el-table-column(type="expand", align="right" )
      template(slot-scope="props")
        p User Name: {{ props.row.userName }}
        p Company Name: {{ props.row.companyName }}
</template>
```

Script:

```
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      rowClicked(row) {
        this.$refs.tableData.toggleRowExpansion(row);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Style - scss

```
// click-able rows
.clickable-rows {
  tbody tr td {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .el-table__expanded-cell {
    cursor: default;
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you trigger `toggleRowExpansion` in Vue3?

Comment: Answer to my previous comment. 

``` lang-js
const tableData = ref(null);

rowClicked(row) {
  tableData.value.$refs.elTable.toggleRowExpansion(row);
}
```

Comment: @MagnusPääru -  <script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const tableData = ref(null);

const rowClicked = (row) => {
  tableData.value.$refs.elTable.toggleRowExpansion(row);
};
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I think there is better way to do so
We have row-key in el-table, and expand-row-keys
So every time you click you can change current expanded row even you can create behavior that "expan-one-at-a-time"
Like: :expand-row-keys="[currentExpandedRow]"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).